# Convert ntext to clob

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, clob, ntext

I have to copy data from one table to another which one table is in Oracle and one is in MSSQL Server. I want to copy the data from MSSQL Server table to Oracle table. The problem is that the MSSQL Server table has one column which is of data type `ntext` and the destination column in Oracle table is `clob`.

When I use the query 
`insert into oracle.table select * from sqlserver.table@mssql;` I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
```

Can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: And if you use varchar(max) which is recommended?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand the comment.

Comment: Stop using ntext http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: The problem is that the tables are already predefined and I have to leave them as they are. The work must be done with the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it through a PL/SQL Procedure and it worked. I created a cursor, passed in the values to my variables declared in VARCHAR2 and then run an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for the `INSERT INTO....SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>@MSSQL`.

Comment: do you have completed script ? tq